# Jade with Express - how to disable ReferenceError

Tags: node.js, pug, express

i want replace empty string instead of ReferenceError. following code :

```
p #{data.data.data}
```

ReferenceError occured when render template that  i want disable it.

Comment: You must give more information : what data (or locals) do you pass to jade when rendering ? Please add your render call code.

Comment: data is not defined.but i want suppress this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an empty object if there is no value when rendering:

`res.render('view/index', {data: your_data_variable || {} });`

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled onto the same thing, but passing an empty object felt wrong. I suggest handling the possibility in the template with something like:

```
- if(data)
  p #{data.data.data}
- else
  p No data for you!
```

Or specify a placeholder inline

```
p #{data.data.data ? data.data.data : 'No data'}
```